# SD Card speed very slow only on Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: dual-boot, 20.10, sd-card, xps, transfer

I have a dual boot laptop computer Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.10.

When I try to read my SD Card from Ubuntu, I get a read speed that is less than 2 MB/s. The same SD Card with the same content works fine when I'm on Windows. The SD card is very good quality, very recent, very fast: I use it for 4k video recording on the drone. This problem is really linked to Ubuntu.

The computer is a Dell XPS 17 9700.

What can I check ?

Comment: What file system type was the SD card formatted as?